# Distorted sound on write

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, signals

I am writing an audio file using python. Here is my code snippet

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from scipy import signal as sig
import soundfile as sf
import IPython

#Actual Content
fs, signal = wavfile.read("whistle_01.wav")
fs2, rir_1_0 = wavfile.read("room_impulse.wav") #Has the same sampling as fs
myaudio = sig.convolve(signal, rir_1_0)
plt.plot(myaudio)
IPython.display.Audio(myaudio, rate=fs)
```

[image]

```
sf.write('test.wav', myaudio, fs)
freq, mysig = wavfile.read("test.wav")
plt.plot(mysig)
```

[image]

The issue is, I display the generated audio sample and then write it. However, when I read the same file after writing, it gets completely changed/distorted. The two figures show the output before and after writing the audio sample. Any pointers, what could be the cause, and how can I correct it?  Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with an audio sample simple/short enough to show simple code that creates it (e.g., a brief pulse of a sine wave)? Can you recreate it without using `scipy.signal.convolve` first, or does that seem to be essential to causing the problem? Please read [mre] and make sure we can reproduce the problem. For example, we can't see the definition of `fs` here, nor the source of `myaudio`.

Comment: Very likely you will need to reduce the `volume` of the signal, if `mysig` is a numpy array just multiply with a very small number like `1e-5` and see if this resolves the distortion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I don't think it is the `convolve()` function that is causing the problem, because, I am plotting it just after the `convolve()`. I have tried using `IPython.display.Audio()`  to play the audio and everything seems fine. However, the problem occurs just when I write that in a file. I am not able to figure out what else happens when I write it. So, my primary goal of posting is to know if I am missing some important knowledge, from the experts!

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen, Thank you for the pointer. I have just tried that. It does reduce the amplitude, but the signal remains the same it seems.

Comment: From the looks of your plots the sample values are in a 16-bit signed int format. You might be best first converting to `float`, normalising the values to ±1 and _then_ performing your convolution, otherwise I could foresee the situation where you overflow the 16-bit limit and essentially scramble the data.

Comment: @fdcpp, Perfect. That's what the issue is. Converting to float resolved everything. Could you please put this as an answer, and I will mark it. This might help somebody someday. In the meantime, some random person just came by and downvoted my post. But I think the issue is genuine.

Comment: @se7en I just made a vague suggestion. Do a write up of how you changed the code, I think you have earned this one.